# SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.otv.managed.bean.UserManagedBean@50e0de15.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I have a question about this error. I am doing tutorial about jsf, hibernate, spring, and maven.

Here is the link to the tutorial.
http://www.onlinetechvision.com/?p=566

Here is the error message that I got.

```
Nov 30, 2012 2:16:56 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: Received 'javax.el.MethodNotFoundException' when invoking action listener '#{userMB.deleteUser(user.id)}' for component 'deleteUser'
Nov 30, 2012 2:16:56 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.otv.managed.bean.UserManagedBean@50e0de15.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:911)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Nov 30, 2012 2:16:56 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt5:users:0, Message=Method not found: com.otv.managed.bean.UserManagedBean@50e0de15.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer)
Nov 30, 2012 2:16:56 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: Method not found: com.otv.managed.bean.UserManagedBean@50e0de15.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer)
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: Method not found: com.otv.managed.bean.UserManagedBean@50e0de15.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:178)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:911)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.otv.managed.bean.UserManagedBean@50e0de15.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    ... 26 more
```

Here is my 'UserManbedBean.java' file.

```
package com.otv.managed.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

import com.otv.model.User;
import com.otv.user.service.IUserService;

/**
 * 
 * User Managed Bean
 * 
 * @author onlinetechvision.com
 * @since 25 Mar 2012
 * @version 1.0.0
 *
 */
@ManagedBean(name="userMB")
@RequestScoped
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String ERROR   = "error";

    //Spring User Service is injected...
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{UserService}")
    IUserService userService;

    List<User> userList;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    /**
     * Add User
     * 
     * @return String - Response Message
     */
    public String addUser() {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(getId());
            user.setName(getName());
            user.setSurname(getSurname());
            getUserService().addUser(user);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return ERROR;
    }

    /**
     * delete User
     * @param id
     */
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        User user =(User)userService.getUserById(id);
        getUserService().deleteUser(user);
    }


    public String deleteAction(User user){
        userList.remove(user);
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Update User
     * @param id
     */
    public void updateUser(int id){
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        user.setName(getName());
        user.setSurname(getSurname());
        getUserService().updateUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Reset Fields
     * 
     */
    public void reset() {
        this.setId(0);
        this.setName("");
        this.setSurname("");
    }

    /**
     * Get User List
     * 
     * @return List - User List
     */
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        userList.addAll(getUserService().getUsers());
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Service
     * 
     * @return IUserService - User Service
     */
    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Service
     * 
     * @param IUserService - User Service
     */
    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    /**
     * Set User List
     * 
     * @param List - User List
     */
    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Id
     * 
     * @return int - User Id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Id
     * 
     * @param int - User Id
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Name
     * 
     * @return String - User Name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Name
     * 
     * @param String - User Name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Surname
     * 
     * @return String - User Surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Surname
     * 
     * @param String - User Surname
     */
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

Here is my 'success.xhtml' file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Welcome to OTV_JSF_Spring_Hibernate_Project</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="USERs : "></h:outputText>
        <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{userMB.userList}" style="width: 10%">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="ID" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Surname" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Action" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="deleteUser" value="Delete" actionListener="#{userMB.deleteUser(user.id)}" action="#{userMB.deleteAction(user)}" /> 
            </p:column>


            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Action" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="updateUser" value="update" actionListener="#{userMB.updateUser(user.id)}" />   
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Here is my UserService.java file

```
package com.otv.user.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.otv.model.User;
import com.otv.user.dao.IUserDAO;

/**
 * 
 * User Service
 * 
 * @author onlinetechvision.com
 * @since 25 Mar 2012
 * @version 1.0.0
 *
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    // UserDAO is injected...
    IUserDAO userDAO;

    /**
     * Add User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        getUserDAO().addUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Delete User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        getUserDAO().deleteUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Update User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        getUserDAO().updateUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     * 
     * @param  int User Id
     */
    @Override
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        return getUserDAO().getUserById(id);
    }

    /**
     * Get User List
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {  
        return getUserDAO().getUsers();
    }

    /**
     * Get User DAO
     * 
     * @return IUserDAO - User DAO
     */
    public IUserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    /**
     * Set User DAO
     * 
     * @param IUserDAO - User DAO
     */
    public void setUserDAO(IUserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

}
```

Here is my UserDAO.java file

```
package com.otv.user.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.otv.model.User;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * 
 * User DAO
 * 
 * @author onlinetechvision.com
 * @since 25 Mar 2012
 * @version 1.0.0
 *
 */

public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * Get Hibernate Session Factory
     * 
     * @return SessionFactory - Hibernate Session Factory
     */
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Set Hibernate Session Factory
     * 
     * @param SessionFactory - Hibernate Session Factory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    /**
     * Delete User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(user);
    }

    /**
     * Update User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(user);
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     * 
     * @param  int User Id
     * @return User 
     */
    @Override
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                                            .createQuery("from User where id=?")
                                            .setParameter(0, id).list();
        return (User)list.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Get User List
     * 
     * @return List - User list
     */
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
        return list;
    }

}
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `int` by `Integer` in your function `public void deleteUser(int id)`.

JSF works only with Objects, you can't use primitive types.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works but updating is not working at all..Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting from the "delete" button? Delete the user and refresh the page without this user?

Comment: @user1834781, aren't you forgetting something? Welcome to Stackoverflow please read the FAQ on how upvoting works.

Answer (score -1):

FORCE class proxies. Spring uses proxy based aop, your managed bean implements an interface hence jdk dynamic proxy instead of class proxy is used.

either remove the interface implementations (Serializable), causing Spring to resort back to CGLIB, or verbosely force the CGLIB proxying, declaring:

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />
```